# Flutter styling is gone

Tags: flutter

I have updated my flutter application to 3.16.0. I do not know why but now the complete styling is gone. Moreless all components has now a gray background color.

Was there any specific change from 3.x.x to 3.16.0?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Material3 is now the default. It gets its theme from a whole different structure. If you're in a rush, you can set `useMaterial3: false` in your `MaterialApp` for now, but that option will go away eventually.

Answer (score 0):

By default, it utilises Material3, however you can now turn it off by setting the useMaterial3 value to false. You may get a thorough explanation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/useMaterial3.html).

Answer (score 0):

Flutter now uses **Material 3 design** but you can use older design,
you can refer material 3 design here https://m3.material.io/

also you can disable this design by using `usematerial3 :false` in themeData

Here is full code for how can you disable material3

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';    
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: false),
        home: const Homepage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```